# Dynamic Regular Expression Yii2

Tags: php, regex, yii2

I want to use dynamic regular expression for model validation in yii2 
for example we use regular expresstion as below:

```
[['password'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_@%&*]{6,32}$/'],
```

now I want to load value of pattern from database. Is it possible ? If it is please explain your soultion.
Thank to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning the regexp to a var

```
$myRegExp = " '/^[A-Za-z0-9_@%&*]{6,32}$/'";
```

then

```
[['password'], 'match', 'pattern' => $myRegExp],
```

You can create a proper class for store and retrieve you regexp string form database. eg: `MyDBRegExpModel` the with a function getMyRegExp($param) retrieve the value you need.. and last add your db access before the return and assignment is r(model) rules

In your Model

```
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
   /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
   public static function tableName()
   {
      return ......;
   }

   /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */     
   public function rules()
   {
       $myModel = MyDBRegExpModel::getMyRegExp($param);

       return [
         ......
         [['password'], 'match', 'pattern' => $myModel->myRegExp],
         ......
        ];
    }
```

Comment: humm very nice solution buddy. ;)

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your soultion